# AMPL API cplex solution time

Tags: operations-research

I have a MILP model written in AMPL and would like to do some computational experiments. I am using AMPL API for Java for controlling the experiments.

Besides others, I want to record the time that CPLEX uses for computing an LP relaxation. I know that in AMPL, I can access it via `_total_solve_time`. Is there a way how to get this value via AMPL API?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a mathematics question.

Comment: I don't understand. It is a question regarding a tool used in mathematics, particularly in OR. If it was about Matlab would it qualify to a mathematics question? Where else should this be asked?

Comment: AMPL has a user forum on Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ampl.